# Setting height and width in Image tag on getting image within table

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. I have declared a div in jsp.
2. I'm sending request to server and getting image in base 64 within table like
3. Each time image is variable dimension.

So now I want to set height and width of image in javaScript.

**script Code**

```
function getSignature(signUrl, accountNumber) {

    $.ajax({
    url: signUrl,
    data: ({accountNumber : accountNumber}),
    success: function(data1) {
    $('#signDiv').show();
    $('#signDiv').html(data1[0]);
    enter code here
    }
    });
    }

in jsp I have declared  
and on click fetcing image and howing in

getting response as
```

Comment: I'm getting image in table like  -  <table><tr><td><IMG src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAA .../><td><tr><table>

Answer (score 0):

You can simply load your image and get its width and height

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "Your base64 image";
if (img.complete) { 
    alert('width: '+img.width);
}
else { 
    img.onload = function() {
       //load if not loaded
alert('width: '+img.width);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to set image height and width in incoming response, in which inage tag will be inside table.

Comment: @Laxman kindly post your code here..we are not getting what you aim to do

Comment: <pre>
function getSignature(signUrl, accountNumber) {
 $.ajax({
  url: signUrl,
  data: ({accountNumber : accountNumber}),
  success: function(data1) {
   $('#signDiv').show();
   $('#signDiv').html(data1[0]);
  }
 });
}

in jsp I have declared <div id="signDiv"></div> 
and on click fetcing image and howing in div

</pre>